# Elixir not creating my tables with default values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, python-elixir

```
class MyObject(Entity):
    name = Field(Unicode(256), default=u'default name', nullable=False)

    using_options(shortnames=True)
    using_mapper_options(save_on_init=False)

    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
```

I am using MySQL in this case, but have also checked against SQLite and I get the same result. It respects `nullable`, but ignores `default` entirely. I don't get any error messages, and it creates the tables just fine. I could go back through and add the defaults, but this is a serious pain that I would like to avoid if possible.

I've tried it with other Field types, but still no joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`default` keyword argument in SQLAlchemy is for Python runtime default value, it's used for INSERT statements. Use `PassiveDefault()` object  as positional argument when you really need database level default.

Comment: I was confused too. But then I've found such behavior quite convenient: no need to update database schema when default is changed, unless it's used somewhere else without SQLAlchemy layer.